# PHP : Curl to login and navigate to another page

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I do have a requirement to use curl to login to page and then from that login session, I have to navigate to another page to grab content. Below is the code that I used. But for some reason, it doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone please help me on it?

```
<?php
//extract data from the post
//set POST variables

$url = 'https://test.curlrul.com/scripts/samplecenter.dll';

$fields = array(
    'cmd' => 'loginsubmit',
    'site' => 'myside',
    'retry' => '0',
    'acct_user_id' => 'myusername',
    'acct_password' => 'mypassword'
);
$fields_string = '';
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie-name');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/mycookie');  //could be empty, but cause problems on some hosts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.curlrul.com/scripts/samplecenter.dll?cmd=partsearch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    print_r($answer);
}

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Where excatly did you get stuck?

Comment: As per the code, I am able to login to the site from the first part of the code. But the second part of the code with new redirect URL is not working. The session doesn't seems to be passed to the new URL.

Comment: If you set `CURLOPT_POST` to `false`, don't call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");` after because this will cause cURL to send a POST request with an empty body which may be affecting the result on the remote end.  Also, it's necessary to encode post parameters, so instead of using the foreach, its easier to just do `$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);`